# Cannot compare DateTimes

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datetime

I'm trying to make a cool little program so when it is a certain date it changes a textbox or label saying something!

```
if (DateTime.Now.Equals(5/15/2016))
{
    textBox1.Text = "Kameron it's your f***ing birthday!";
    label1.Text = "It's your birthday!";
}
```

Comment: Congratulations if you have done it.. Now what's the question..

Comment: I'm wondering why? Also is there a way I can add like a time to it like the current time in 12 hour form instead of 24?

Comment: I have the code in a timer and so when the program loads it starts the timer. But it does nothing I want it to do. It doesn't change the textbox text or label text

Comment: You can't just type in a date anywhere in the code. You need to *create* a date object which represents the 15th of may, 2016. For example, `DateTime.Today.Equals(new DateTime(2016, 05, 15))`. Next time, please show us the error messages you get, rather than saying "it doesn't work" - it not working is clear, since the question exists, and it's nice not to have to guess what problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it to `DateTime` and compare the `Date` part of the `DateTime.Now`

```
if (DateTime.Now.Date.Equals(new DateTime(2016,5,15)))
{
      textBox1.Text = "Kameron it's your f***ing birthday!";
      label1.Text = "It's your birthday!";
}
```

Alternatively (as @rob suggested) you could use `DateTime.Today` and do the comparison.

```
if( DateTime.Today.Equals(new DateTime(2016,5,15)))
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Small suggestion: `DateTime.Now.Date` can be replaced with simply `DateTime.Today` :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Equals("5/16/2016"))
{
     textBox1.Text = "Kameron it's your f***ing birthday!";
     label1.Text = "It's your birthday!";
}
```

Comment: This will only work in certain parts of the world - which would be fun to debug ;). There's no reason to convert a date to a string when `DateTime` already provides comparison methods